# how to integrate facebook with a portal website?

Tags: java, html

I'm using RAD as a tool for integrating facebook into a portal website. I want to know how to share(post) a particular item or content on my portal website to facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [facebook](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/) API. Here are some example of [How to use](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/wiki/Examples) the API